# How to avoid parsing the contents of strings in a macro

Tags: macros, dataframe, metaprogramming, julia

I'm lazy, and got tired of selecting rows in dataframes with code like this (on the 0.4 RC):

```
using DataFrames
data = DataFrame(num=[1,2,3,4], let=["A", "B", "A", "B"])
subset = data[(data[:num].>1)&(data[:let].=="B"),:]
```

so I wrote the following macro

```
# Need to import SubstitutionString from Base
macro sel(dt, conditions) 
    dtstr=string(dt)
    str = string(conditions)
    out_str = replace(str, r":\w+",SubstitutionString(string(dtstr, "[", "\\g<0>", "]"))) 
    out_str = string(dtstr, "[", out_str, ",:]")
    eval(parse(out_str))
end
```

so that I could instead write

```
subset = @sel data (:num.>1)&(:let.=="B")
```

This works fine, except in the situation where I want to match columns to strings like "Turtles::Leonardo" or "12:25:00".  Is there any way to avoid falsely identifying the contents of strings as column names here, or is this a limitation of this sloppy convert-to-string-and-work-on-that metaprogramming?

Comment: `import Base.SubstitutionString` ? please tell me the way to import SubstitutionString

Comment: I should have mentioned -- this only works on 0.4 -- it looks like there have been some changes to replacements since 3.11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also take a look at `DataFramesMeta`, where you find a similar macro, which should work in the problematic cases you mention. The macro works this way:

```
subset = @where(data, (:num.>1)&(:let.=="B"))
```

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted... only better.

Answer (score 0):

is it helps?

```
out_str = replace(str, r"(\()(:\w)",SubstitutionString(string(dtstr, "[", "\\g<2>", "]")))
```